# If I start a new game, can I redeem my mystery gift torchic now that the promotion is over?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I currently have the mystery gift on my cartridge but was thinking about starting a new game. Would I be able to use that mystery gift on my new game or would it disappear or not be usable since it's been used previously and the event is over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, event is over, sorry!

I'm sure people might have some speed boost torchics left over however

Comment: I found a few old posts on gamefaqs that said otherwise, but I'm betting because of the age of the posts it was only possible since the event was still going on. Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 9):

You should check out [Pokemon Bank](http://www.pokemonbank.com/en-us/).

For $5 a year, you get 100 boxes in the cloud so you never have to lose a pokemon again. You can easily transport all your pokes from game to game and save to save (with exception of held items), given you have your own 3DS with your credentials on it and a WiFi-connection.

Pokemon Bank is compatible with Generation 6 and onwards (supposedly).

Comment: I was reading the site. Looks like it's official (from Nintendo) and you have extras (like winning Celebi, Battle points and other stuff) Really nice from Nintendo to do that =D

Comment: @Michel Beware, the Celebi is only available through the rest of this month (September 2014). Go to the eShop as soon as possible, don't hesitate, because there's a free 30-day trail!